# Is there a way to limit display resolution options in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, scaling, pixels

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to restrict or edit the list of possible resolutions offered in the Windows 10 Display Settings.

I would want to make sure that if the user changes the resolution, the only options available would ensure that the pixels that Windows is displaying are made up of either 1, 4, or 9 physical pixels of the monitor.  If the native resolution of the display is 3840x2160, viable choices would be 3840x2160, 1920x1080, 1280x720, etc.

An invalid resolution like (for example) 1536x864 would result in Windows pixels that are 2.5 x 2.5 physical pixels and would introduce artifacts in the image because of the fractional pixel.  That is what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Are you sure the display does the kind of scaling you want? Because most don't.

Answer (score 0):

Windows expects a monitor to communicate its
[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
in the process that is called Auto Detection.
The EDID contains all that Windows knows about the monitor, and this information
dictates how the display driver works with that monitor and is the list
of resolutions that Windows displays.

So basically you're asking how modify or override the list of resolutions
that the monitor communicates to Windows.

If one has an NVIDIA Quatro display card, this can be done
[via the NVIDIA control panel](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3569/%7E/managing-a-display-edid-on-windows),
using the "system topology" section.
It is not implemented for the GeForce line of monitors.

The other option is to use a utility that creates a custom EDID profile,
to set up a permanent profile in Windows so that it does not contact the monitor.

Below are a couple of utilities. They are pretty old, but have been
reported as working for many years and up to very recently.
I don't know how well they work in the latest versions of Windows 10.

- [Custom Resolution Utility](http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) (open-source)
- [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) (discontinued) was once the best of its kind

More recent software which might help:

- [ControlMyMonitor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html) -
  one of the excellent Nirsoft utilities

Useful reference :
[Understanding EDID](https://www.extron.com/article/uedid).

---

Microsoft has an article about how to override the monitor's EDID through
a crafted `.inf` file (which I never tried):
[Overriding Monitor EDIDs with an INF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/overriding-monitor-edids).